# Custom logic for matching with Scala parser combinators

Tags: scala, dsl, parser-combinators

I'm using Scala parser combinators to write parsers for a DSL for a constraint programming language that I'm working on. One of the things I'd like to be able to parse are expressions of the form:

```
<resource1> <relationship_name> <resource2>
```

For example:

```
Teacher canTeach Class
```

I'm trying to match this using:

```
stringLiteral ~ stringLiteral ~ stringLiteral
```

But what I really want is to be able to match it by looking up if the first and last strings are defined resources and if the middle one is actually a relationship that is in scope.

How can I define a function that allows me to put these conditions on matching and then use it.

Comment: Are the resources and relationships defined in the language?

Comment: @TravisBrown no they're not - they're defined by the user at runtime. Imagine a REPL.

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference between *grammar* and *syntax*. `stringLiteral ~ stringLiteral ~ stringLiteral` has no restrictions on what `stringLiteral` is - even if you add some restriction (like `stringLiteral ~ "canTeach" | "canWhatever" ~ stringLiteral`)" - it should be known before parser is constructed (not during parsing itself). However, your desirable restriction is seems to be *semantical* which means that some grammatically correct sentences like "Teacher canTeach Microwave" may not be semantically correct - so this check should be done after parsing. You have AST as parser's output - so you could just validate this AST, something like:

```
case class Knowledge(subject: String, can: Boolean, predicate: String, obj: String)

val knowledges = parse("Teacher can teach Class", "Teacher cannot teach Class")

knowledges.groupBy(x => (x.subject, x.predicate, x.obj)).mapValues(v => if(v.forall(v.head.can == _.can)) Right(v) else Left(v)))
```